# Can someone help me on how to automatically extract an image out of this larger picture?

Tags: python, image-processing, deep-learning, computer-vision, python-imaging-library

I am working on a computer vision project and the pictures shown below are my inputs. I am trying to crop out the pictures of cats out of these images. Can someone help me with this task?
[Example1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XO4UZ.jpg)

[Example2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfV7T.jpg)

[Example3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpGJg.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

One possible way I believe you could solve this problem is by using an algorithm called [Mask R-CNN](https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN). You would have to have a data set of hundreds of images that you would have to physically annotate, then train a model referencing those images. After you have trained your model and have generated some weights, you then should be able to detect cats in images successfully, and if you train your model well enough, you could even detect them in tougher images that the ones that you have linked.